# What's the right content-type for a Java jar file?

Tags: mime-types, content-type

I'm uploading some jars into s3 and want to set the right content-type headers for them.

I looked through [what I thought was a comprehensive list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), and was unable to find any mention of jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) says it's `application/java-archive` though I don't see that in any rfc or standards document.

Comment: It can also not be found in IANA's [media-type registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

Comment: Weirdly enough, you can find [OSGi's JAR file extension](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.osgi.bundle) which specifies `2. File extension(s) : .jar`

Answer (score 13):

I found a list which might be very useful to some.

You can find a more complete (but still incomplete) list of MIME-Types [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) from the official Mozilla Developers Network.

For Java Archive (JAR) .jar files the correct type is indeed:

```
.jar   |   application/java-archive
```

Comment: Oddly this "complete list of MIME-Types" is specifically titled "Incomplete list of MIME types."

Answer (score 4):

I have seen instances of these content-type headers for JAR files:

#### application/java-archive

#### application/x-java-archive

#### application/x-jar